# Is a car owned by a trust a "commercial" vehicle?

Tags: united-states, taxes, car, trusts

If a car is owned by a trust, does it have to be registered as a commercial vehicle, or can it be considered a personal vehicle?

Since commercial vehicles have much higher tax rates, this has tax implications.

Comment: I think this is too broad, as written.  I think it would depend on the state, the specifics of the trust (a charitable trust vs a family trust), the purpose for which the car is used, e.g. personal use by a family trust's beneficaries, or for a charitable trust employee to do business?

Answer (score 2):

I would think that *most* if not *all* US states would *not* consider a vehicle owned by an *individual* trust a commercial vehicle.  While there may be some commercial entities that are classified as a "trust", a trust meant to hold assets on behalf of one or more individuals (for estate planning purposes, for example) should not be considered a "commercial" entity.

Comment: The state here has no problem with my trust-owned vehicle being registered as an individual.  (Except they're a little stupid about the insurance situation--all owners must be insured, whether they are drivers or not.)